# Set lang tag in iframe as the value of parent lang tag HTML

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an application inside of an iframe which needs to be translated. However the language which needs to be used is set in the parent lang tag.

Is there any way to get the lang value of the parent and set it as the lang value in the iframe?

Comment: is the iframe domain same as the parent window?

Answer (score 0):

No, not by default. Webpages displayed in an iframe are still a separate document and can't be easily manipulated from the outside. However, there are some workaround, maybe this one will work for you:

https://developers.localizejs.com/docs/translating-content-in-iframes

It is a basic cdn library will help you translating it. It's required that page, which you want to show, implements this solution too.